# Strange WPF Data Binding behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to get some databinding to work in my application, but I am having lots of problems. Here is one example:

**This  does not work:** (No text is displayed in the textblock, but the UpdateConsole function IS triggered though, **and the `TextPercentage` IS updating if I break at it**)

SmallWindow.xaml:

```
<Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click1"/>
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding TextPercentage}">
```

SmallWindows.xaml.cs (with some unrelated logic removed)

```
public partial class SmallWindow : Window
{
     public SmallWindow()
     {
      DataContext = new ViewModel();

      private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        ViewModel mv = new ViewModel();
        mv.UpdateConsole();
      }
  }
}
```

ViewModel.cs (with other unrelated code removed)

```
private string textPercentage;
    public string TextPercentage
    {
        get { return textPercentage; }
        set
        {
            textPercentage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TextPercentage");
        }
    }
private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     public void UpdateConsole()
    {
        ++_count;
        TextPercentage= string.Format("{0}", _count);
    }
```

**This DOES work:** (Text IS displayed in the textblock)

Smallwindow.xaml

```
<Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding ChangeSongCommand}"/>
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding TextPercentage}"/>
```

SmallWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class SmallWindow : Window
{
     public SmallWindow()
     {
      DataContext = new ViewModel();
     }
}
```

ViewModel.cs (with other unrelated code removed)

```
private string textPercentage;
    public string TextPercentage
    {
        get { return textPercentage; }
        set
        {
            textPercentage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TextPercentage");
        }
    }
private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

 public ICommand ChangeSongCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(UpdateConsole); } }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void UpdateConsole(object obj)
    {
        ++_count;
        TextPercentage= string.Format("{0}", _count);
    }
```

So, the main difference is, the second one which works, is triggered by an ICommand.

Have been battling with this all day, and I don't know why this occurs?
Bit of a beginner, so please answer in simple terms :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is you are not calling the method on the right object:

```
// Create a separate view model object, which the current view is not bound to
ViewModel mv = new ViewModel();
mv.UpdateConsole();
```

This creates a new object and calls `UpdateConsole` on it, but the WPF view is looking at the `ViewModel` instance referred to by the `DataContext` property.

What you want is:

```
// Get the view model object the view is presently bound to
ViewModel mv = (ViewModel)DataContext;
mv.UpdateConsole();
```

Comment: Hello! Yes that works! For bonus points, I am trying to do the same thing from another class. (A separate class, not a xaml code behind, but DataContext is not found, where can I get that DataContext, or something else from?

Comment: This general problem is known as "dependency resolution" and there are a number of approaches you can take to deal with it. The two basic categories are putting the object you want to access (the dependency) somewhere you can always find it, like a static field (e.g. global resolution), or have someway to construct the depending object and give it its dependency (dependency inversion). They each have downsides: tight coupling and complexity respectively. For small projects, static fields work great, but for larger projects you'll likely want dependency inversion.